# How to run script on specific instance group in EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-ec2, mapreduce, amazon-emr

I am stuck with a task, where I have to run 1 script only on Task instance group instances.

**My current approach-**

For this, I passes script as a Bootstrap Actions while cluster launch, but it run scripts on all machines. (master, core, task instance groups).

Can you please help me to run that script only on specific(task) instance group ?

Actual task is to run termination notice polling script on task instance groups instances. - https://blog.fugue.co/2015-01-06-spot-termination-notices.html

Comment: Do you have to run that script at time of launch or you can run it any time?

Comment: @error2007s My use case is, whenever any spot instance(under task instance groups) goes down, just replace with new instance.

So, as per my understanding, if I pass this as bootstrap action, then it will always run on all task instances, even if we launch new instances also.

Correct me, if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the file **/mnt/var/lib/info/extraInstanceData.json** which contains the key **instanceRole** value which is either master, core or task.
For example, add this to your script:

```
INSTANCE_ROLE=$(jq .instanceRole /mnt/var/lib/info/extraInstanceData.json)
```

Or, you can use this file **/mnt/var/lib/info/instance.json** that exists on any node in the cluster, it looks like this:

```
  {
    "instanceGroupId": "ig-XXXXXXXXXX",
    "isMaster": false
  }
```

You can match the ig-XXXXXXXXXX to your cluster's TASK group ID.